# Missing embed tool in Wygwam?

Tags: wygwam

I recently purchased and installed WYGWAM 3.1.1 and noticed that in the embed feature is missing. 5 o'clock on a Friday might have something to do with it, but I can't seem to find it.  I would rather not have my client click on the "Source" button to add such things as well.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If you’re referring to Embed Media, it’s still there, it just has a different icon than it did in Wgywam 2 (as with all the other buttons). It’s the one that looks like a chunk of a video reel’s tape.

Answer (score 0):

Embed what?

Go to Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Wygwam, you'll see Editor configurations. Select Full or Basic.

[image: Wygwam Toolbar]

Drag and drop the controls you want or don't want from/to the toolbar. click on an item to disable/enable.

Ensure that your field is set to the appropriate configuration.

[image: Wygwam Field options]